Massive grey area appearing at bottom of page
If I scroll to the very bottom of my app's home page (there are a few thousands records listed each on one line so it takes a while!) at the bottom there is grey space that is about 6 times the height of the phone screen. It gives the impression to the user the screen has frozen because they scroll down at high speed so get to the bottom of the grey space (the 2nd attached screenshot), then when they scroll up at a normal pace they don't get above the grey space before giving up and assuming the app is frozen.
Please do you know what may be causing this? (If I filter this list the bug doesn't happen - I don't know if that's because I used the filter function or just because the list is shorter)
Code:
class _ItemListState extends State {

    _ItemListState({Key? key}) {
    _stream = _reference.snapshots();
    _foundItems = items; // Initialize _foundItems with items
  }

  final Query _reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('test_data_table').orderBy(
      "dlastupd", descending: true);
  late final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _stream;
  late List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> _foundItems;
  final List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> items = [];

  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    setState(() {
      if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {

        _foundItems = items;

      } else {
        _foundItems = items
            .where((item) =>
            item["name"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
            .toList();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Updates'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _stream,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text('Some error occurred ${snapshot.error}'));
                }
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
                  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = querySnapshot.docs;
                  items.clear(); // Clear items to avoid duplication
                  items.addAll(documents.map((e) =>
                  {
                    'name': e['name']
                  }));

                  return ListView.builder(

                      itemCount: _foundItems.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        Map thisItem = _foundItems[index];

                        return ListTile(
                          title:

                          Text.rich(
                              TextSpan(
                                  children: [
                                    TextSpan(text: thisItem['name'],
                                        )
                                  ]
                              )
                          ),

                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(
                              context,
                              '/factfile',
                              arguments: {
                                'id': thisItem['id'],
                              },
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      });
                }
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}




If you are running your app in release mode. Just try to run it in debug mode and check on console if any error occurs or not

Hi @Aks it is in debug mode and has no errors (I’ve turned off the debug mode labels in order to take screenshots for the App Store)
